# How to edit the vertices of Mesh in box geometry using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertices

If I have a cube then how can I change its vertices:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xce8b11, transparent: true} );
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 400, 20 );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.position.x = 300;
cube.position.y = 300;
scene.add( cube );
```

Comment: I added vertices like cube.geometry.vertices[1].y = 430; but cannot find a good example which explains how to achieve custom shape & what vertices[1].y is ?

Comment: `vertices[1]` is a vertex of the shape. Each vertex has a x, y, and z value that positions it in the scene. `vertices[1].y` is the y value. To create a custom shape out of a cube, you can change the x, y, and z values of all eight of its vertices.

Comment: Edited question text